# Generate sitemap automatically

Tags: web-development, mind-mapping

I'm wondering if it's possible to visualize the sitemap of a website. I found this [website](http://brahms.iet.unipi.it/) but that webpage doesn't contain the links to the other webpages like [this one](http://brahms.iet.unipi.it/nanoele/depot17/nanoele8.html).

So far I tried [xml-sitemaps](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/) but it doesn't work; idem for the Google Chrome's extension [Sitemap Generator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitemap-generator/hcnjemngcihnhncobgdgkkfkhmleapah?hl=en).

Answer (score -1):

[image]You can try [Octopus.do](https://octopus.do) XML generator. Insert the url by using this [link](https://octopus.do/sitemap/resource/generator) and then press Import "Pages only" or "With meta tags" optionally. Octopus.do helps to visualize any website structure from Internet.
And the main purpose of Octopus.do to help you create your own site sitemap by using "Content brick method" which is very easy in work, just drag and drop content blocks.
Octopus.do also has a low fidelity wireframe collection for prototyping website structure and UX architecture.

Comment: Hello @Vera thank you for your answer. The service you suggested is used to create the sitemap of your website, not to see the sitemap of a third party website.

Comment: Hi Gennaro! Thanks, I see. But I just used it for another website...and it shows another website sitemap..

Comment: can you tell me where to copy the website url please?

Comment: You can insert the url by using this link https://octopus.do/sitemap/resource/generator and then Import  "Pages only" or "With meta tags" optionally.

Comment: I tried and I got the error "Sitemap.xml file is absent or have errors.", so maybe I need a tool able to create the sitemap by itself without a sitemap.xml file.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it happens with the big heavy websites. But with the smaller one it works perfect.

Comment: Please explain a bit your answer. A screenshot isn't a proper answer, you should also include a link to the recommended program, a brief explanation of how it solves the question and its main featutes.

Comment: @Alejandro my answer is updated. Please let me know if you need any additional information.